# sails.js upload file to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, file-upload, sails.js

So sails.js uses [skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) for file upload. Since I'm using heroku to deploy my app I can't simply use the file system for file storage. Is there a way to pipe the file upload to a postgresql db as a blob?

Comment: I am assuming you saw this? https://github.com/skipperjs/skipper-postgresql I am new to using sails/skipper, so I haven't been able to actually get this working. There is also a skipper-memory module that I have gotten to work, which never touches disk. You then have to build your own file object for putting in Postgres